# How to normalize tweets in Histogram using R language?

Tags: r, twitter, histogram, normalization, tweets

I retrieved Twitter tweets for various hashtags with different tracking period. For example, hashtag1 was tracked for 6 days, Hashtag2 tracked for 4 days, Hashtag3 tracked for 2 days. How can I normalize each hashtag? How can I divide them into equal quarters? Thanks in advance...Here is the code ......>

```
    library(streamR)
    library(rjson)

    setwd("/Users/Desktop")
    Tweets = parseTweets("Hashtag1.json")
    table(Tweets$created_at)

    dated_Tweets <- as.POSIXct(Tweets$created_at, format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S   
    +0000 %Y")

    hist(dated_Tweets, breaks="hours", freq=TRUE, xlab="dated_Tweets", main= 
    "Distribution of tweets", col="blue")
```

Comment: Can you show us what do you get right now, and explain what exactly are you not happy with?  Do you want something like _tweets per day_ for each of the hashtags?

Comment: Yes I visualized the histogram for each hashtag, but each hashtag has a different tracking period, so I want to normalize each hashtag. For example, I want to divide each day which is 24 hours into 4 quarters (every 6 hours) then accumulate all days together at the same histogram.

Comment: So you have tweet timestamp.  You want to create histogram of "day quarters" for each tweet?  You want to see if #2 is tweeted more, say in morning hours, and #4 at night?

Comment: @OttToomet yes exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main stumbling block is to convert date-times to 6-hour bins.  You can achieve this with `format.POSIXct` and `cut`.  Here is a suggestion, complete with a histogram.  There are many ways to do the histograms, maybe you will prefer a table instead.

```
   library(magrittr)
   library(ggplot2)
   ## create some tweet times
   hash1 <- lubridate::ymd("20170101") + lubridate::seconds(runif(100, 0, 10*86400))
   hash2 <- lubridate::ymd("20170101") + lubridate::seconds(runif(100, 0, 31*86400))
   hash3 <- lubridate::ymd("20170101") + lubridate::seconds(runif(300, 0, 5*86400))
   ## bin these into 6h intervals
   bins1 <- format(hash1, "%H") %>%
       as.numeric() %>%
           cut(breaks=c(0,6,12,18,24), include.lowest = TRUE)
   hTags <- data.frame(tag="#1", bins=bins1)
   bins2 <- format(hash2, "%H") %>%
       as.numeric() %>%
           cut(breaks=c(0,6,12,18,24), include.lowest = TRUE)
   hTags <- rbind(hTags,
                  data.frame(tag="#2", bins=bins2 ))
   bins3 <- format(hash3, "%H") %>%
       as.numeric() %>%
           cut(breaks=c(0,6,12,18,24), include.lowest = TRUE)
   hTags <- rbind(hTags,
                  data.frame(tag="#3", bins=bins3 ))
   ggplot(data=hTags, aes(x=bins, fill=tag)) + geom_bar(position="dodge", aes(y=..prop.., group=tag))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you! but where I can read the JSON file here? @OttToomet

Comment: You should read and parse these where I created the random ones.  I don't have your data so I had to come up with my own...

Comment: Yes, thank you. I figured it out, but I have two questions. 1- how to normalize each bin? 2- how to get the numeric value for each bin?

Comment: What exactly do you mean as "normalization"?  Do you want red + green + blue = 1 for each 6h group?  Do you mean reds across 6h groups = 1, and other colors too?  You can get numeric values by `table(hTags$tab, hTags$bins)` but, again, it depends on what exactly do you want to get.

Comment: Yes, I mean reds across 6h groups = 1

Comment: Thank you very much for your ultimate help

Comment: Happy to help :-)  Please accept the answer if you end up using this idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chron package and deal only with hours by converting into bins as written in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37666558/7418254